# Javascript DIV Not Displaying After Changing CSS

Tags: javascript, css, dom, styles, display

I have a DIV for spinner:

```
<div id="spinner" style="display:none;z-index:100;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-50px; margin-left:-50px;">
     <img src="..\spinner.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
```

The code document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block" changes the style of the spinner to block but the spinner div not showing:

```
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";

getAllStudents(); //this function gets data from MySQL tables and populate a table on the page

document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Check if you don't have any other css for spinner
Also provide an html template for this code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `display: none;` after the function call,
try adding the code  just before you start populating the table on page.

```js
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: If I delete the document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none", the spinner is showed but after populating the table, which is not wanted. I want the user to see waiting spinner during fetching the data and populating the table

Comment: @Shubair the problem is that the HTTP request will be *started* almost immediately. The browser won't flash the `<div>` on and off. You can turn it off when you get the *response* to the HTTP request.

Comment: When you call the `getAllStudents();` function, set the `dsiplay to block`.  & when you done with populating the data, set the `display to none`.

Answer (score 0):

Two Ideas:

1. If the image `src` is incorrect, I've sometimes found it doesn't display anything, even with an `alt = "Loading"` tag. You might want to test the link it's displaying the image from to verify it works. (Don't just test the `src` link).
2. Assuming the image `src` is correct, you could remove the image from `<div id="spinner"/>` and add it separately as `<img id="spinner" src="..\spinner.gif" alt="Loading" />` and then you could have your `<div` show what you want.

EDIT: (3 ideas now)

3. Change your `src` attribute so all of the `\` characters are replaced with `/`. I tried an image in my own script with `src = "..\spinner.png"` and it wouldn't even run, but doing `src = "../spinner.png"` did. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I tested the second idea still not showing :-(

Comment: Sorry. Thought it might be worth a try.  Have been able to have the spinner show at any point without anything else running in the script?

Comment: Yes, if I call document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block" before AJAX get function and call document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none" after AJAX get function, the spinner showing. It is not showing when the browser busy exciting other code, i.e. populating the table. Is there any way to refresh the DIV spinner before calling getAllStudents() function?

Comment: @Shubair, I think I have it. just replace all of the '\' characters in your image source with '/' and it should display perfectly. Let me know if this doesn't work.